# Read blocks A when checking foreign constraint on B

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, stored-procedures, foreign-keys

I have a table, table B, with foreign key to table A. Both tables are relatively large.

In my update procedure for table B, I first disable the constraint, update stuff, then enable the constraint.

```
ALTER TABLE B NOCHECK CONSTRAINT ALL;
-- Update table b
ALTER TABLE B WITH CHECK CHECK CONSTRAINT ALL;
```

The problem is that last line takes a while to run 10-15 minutes and while it's running, reads from table A are really slow! Table A is required for a web application and the application will timeout when this is running.

First question: Why is this happening? I would think that this would just be a shared lock on table A and that it wouldn't block other reads.

Second question: How can I avoid this?

Thanks!

Comment: This appears to be a question where the answer will depend on the type/version of the database you're using. So would you mind adding a tag for that?  For example row level locking isn't a feature everywhere.

Comment: I believe only SQL Server uses that strange WITH CHECK CHECK syntax :)

Comment: This dba.SE posting creates a case where re-enabling the constraint with a NOCHECK option will allow invalid data to remain in the table: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/167861/what-is-a-with-check-check-constraint

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> First question: Why is this happening?

Because you asked for every B row to have every one of its FKs validated.

ALTER TABLE B **WITH CHECK** CHECK CONSTRAINT ALL;

That may well be more expensive than just leaving the constraint enforced during your update.

You can disable/enable-with-check for just the FK to A (if there are multiple).  Or you can disable/enable-with-nocheck to re-enable the constraint but to leave it unenforced for the changes you made in your update procedure (and untrusted by the query optimizer).

ALTER TABLE B **WITH NOCHECK** CHECK CONSTRAINT ALL;

You might then schedule a task to check all the rows.

> I would think that this would just be a shared lock on table A and that it wouldn't block other reads.

The ALTER TABLE affects both A and B, as DELETE and UPDATE queries on A enforce the FK.  So the ALTER TABLE takes Sch-M locks on A, B and the FK object.  EG:

```
use tempdb

drop table if exists B
drop table if exists A

create table A(id int primary key)
create table B(id int, aid int references A)

insert into A(id) values (1)

insert into b(id,aid) values (1,1)

begin transaction

ALTER TABLE B WITH CHECK CHECK CONSTRAINT ALL 

select object_name(resource_associated_entity_id) object_name, request_mode
from sys.dm_tran_locks 
where request_session_id = @@spid 
  and resource_type = 'OBJECT'
  and request_mode = 'Sch-M'    
rollback
```

outputs:

```
object_name                      request_mode
-------------------------------- -------------
FK__B__aid__412EB0B6             Sch-M
B                                Sch-M
A                                Sch-M

(3 rows affected)
```